# matrics merge by column names (partically common and different set to NA) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge two datasets like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame (id=paste("id",1:10, sep=""), a=1:10, b= 11:20, d=21:30)
data2 <- data.frame(id=paste("id", 11:20, sep=""), a=1:10, b=11:20, e= 21:30)
```

The merged data will have all common columns and merged by column "id".

```
   id  a  b  d  e
1   1  1 11 21 NA
2   2  2 12 22 NA
3   3  3 13 23 NA
4   4  4 14 24 NA
5   5  5 15 25 NA
6   6  6 16 26 NA
7   7  7 17 27 NA
8   8  8 18 28 NA
9   9  9 19 29 NA
10 10 10 20 30 NA
11 11  1 11 NA 21
12 12  2 12 NA 22
13 13  3 13 NA 23
14 14  4 14 NA 24
15 15  5 15 NA 25
16 16  6 16 NA 26
17 17  7 17 NA 27
18 18  8 18 NA 28
19 19  9 19 NA 29
20 20 10 20 NA 30
```

You can see the missing columns are added and values are set to NA. The manual work around would like this, but looking for elegant way to do in R which a large number of variables are mismatching :

```
data1$e=NA
data2$d = NA
rbind(data1, data2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use `dplyr::bind_rows()` instead of `rbind()`. That'll give you the behavior you want with no additional lifting.

```r
data1 <- data.frame (id=1:10, a=1:10, b= 11:20, d=21:30)
data2 <- data.frame(id=11:20, a=1:10, b=11:20, e= 21:30)

dplyr::bind_rows(data1, data2)
#>    id  a  b  d  e
#> 1   1  1 11 21 NA
#> 2   2  2 12 22 NA
#> 3   3  3 13 23 NA
#> 4   4  4 14 24 NA
#> 5   5  5 15 25 NA
#> 6   6  6 16 26 NA
#> 7   7  7 17 27 NA
#> 8   8  8 18 28 NA
#> 9   9  9 19 29 NA
#> 10 10 10 20 30 NA
#> 11 11  1 11 NA 21
#> 12 12  2 12 NA 22
#> 13 13  3 13 NA 23
#> 14 14  4 14 NA 24
#> 15 15  5 15 NA 25
#> 16 16  6 16 NA 26
#> 17 17  7 17 NA 27
#> 18 18  8 18 NA 28
#> 19 19  9 19 NA 29
#> 20 20 10 20 NA 30
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: works great with numberical vectors but produce error 1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector for factors

Comment: @SHRram what data did you use to generate that error?

Comment: Actually my real data has factors, see I revised the question to reflect this to my real situation, thank you quick response

Comment: The original data looks unchanged to me